# Split Time Series Data Into Time Intervals in one line (PythonicWay) - Hourly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a minute data that has the time column. I want to create new column  with just  `hours` with date time format, for example `format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. I know in R, we can use something like,

```
value$hour<- cut(as.POSIXct(paste(value$time),
                          format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), breaks="hour")
```

When I do this, I get the following output, (which i need)

```
time                 hour
2017-02-10 00:00:00  2017-02-10 00:00:00
2017-02-10 00:01:00  2017-02-10 00:00:00
2017-02-10 00:02:00  2017-02-10 00:00:00
2017-02-10 00:03:00  2017-02-10 00:00:00
....
2017-12-1 10:05:00   2017-12-01 10:00:00
2017-12-1 10:06:00   2017-12-01 10:00:00
```

I am also aware that there are many threads that discusses about `dt.date`, `dt.hour` etc. I can do the following in python like this,

```
value['date'] = value['time'].dt.date
value['hour'] = value['time'].dt.hour
```

Is there any way that I can do in python that is similar to R as mentioned above in one line? 
Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['hour'] = df['time'].dt.floor('H')
print (df)
                 time                hour
0 2017-02-10 00:00:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
1 2017-02-10 00:01:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
2 2017-02-10 00:02:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
3 2017-02-10 00:03:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
4 2017-12-01 10:05:00 2017-12-01 10:00:00
5 2017-12-01 10:06:00 2017-12-01 10:00:00
```

If need convert to `datetime` column `time` add [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('H')
print (df)
                  time                hour
0  2017-02-10 00:00:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
1  2017-02-10 00:01:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
2  2017-02-10 00:02:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
3  2017-02-10 00:03:00 2017-02-10 00:00:00
4   2017-12-1 10:05:00 2017-12-01 10:00:00
5   2017-12-1 10:06:00 2017-12-01 10:00:00
```

Comment: thank you, as you have `df['time'].dt.floor('H')` does the trick as I already converted `df['time']` to `pd.to_datetime`. however, my new colum `hour` only shows the date and missing `00:00:00` part. Any thought why?

Comment: Yes, in pandas it is not displayed if all values are `00:00:00`. But if check value by `print (df.loc[0, 'time'])` it retutn also missing zeros.

Comment: perfect, you meant `print (df.loc[0, 'hour'])` right? This works perfect, awesome, thank you!

Comment: I have to put the flag where it changes, how can I do that?