# How can I split TimeSeries Data at every 10 minutes using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, time-series

how can I break my `TimeSeries` data at every 10 minutes of period, here is my sample data, in the following data, if I see first there is no 10 minutes of data, because after 3rd row it jumps to `00:39:00` minutes so it will start the counting again here from `0`, I want to put the true/false values where it ends up counting 10 minutes.

I tried one technique `x["DateTime"].diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)` but it finds the 00:10:00 timestamps in the data and then it breaks it, which is not as per my requirements. because `pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)` gives the results `00:10:00`

how can I possibly do that? I hope I explained it clearly

```
DateTime               ValA
2011-01-01 00:01:00    0.551815
2011-01-01 00:01:59    0.542464
2011-01-01 00:03:00    0.520525
2011-01-03 06:39:00    1.225518
2011-01-03 06:40:00    2.241443
2011-01-03 06:40:59    3.148734
2011-01-03 06:42:00    5.361565
2011-01-03 06:43:00    6.878603
2011-01-03 06:43:59    7.127448
2011-01-03 06:45:00    8.130982
2011-01-03 06:46:00    8.188750
2011-01-03 06:46:59    8.267185
2011-01-03 06:48:00    8.204753
2011-01-03 06:49:00    8.121145
2011-01-03 06:49:59    8.129115
2011-01-03 06:51:00    8.160426
2011-01-03 06:52:00    8.301057
2011-01-03 06:53:00    8.342608
2011-01-03 06:53:59    8.390675
2011-01-03 06:55:00    8.063992
2011-01-03 06:56:00    7.396055
2011-01-03 06:56:59    6.771710
2011-01-03 06:58:00    5.295999
2011-01-03 06:59:00    4.210010
2011-01-03 06:59:59    3.689164
2011-01-03 07:01:00    2.963554
2011-01-03 07:02:00    2.873527
2011-01-03 07:02:59    2.885474
2011-01-03 07:04:00    2.394660
2011-01-03 07:05:00    2.603989
```

the desired output should be

```
DateTime               ValA       Flag
2011-01-01 00:01:00    0.551815   False 
2011-01-01 00:01:59    0.542464   False
2011-01-01 00:03:00    0.520525   False
2011-01-03 06:39:00    1.225518   True
2011-01-03 06:40:00    2.241443   False
2011-01-03 06:40:59    3.148734   False
2011-01-03 06:42:00    5.361565   False
2011-01-03 06:43:00    6.878603   False
2011-01-03 06:43:59    7.127448   False
2011-01-03 06:45:00    8.130982   False
2011-01-03 06:46:00    8.188750   False
2011-01-03 06:46:59    8.267185   False
2011-01-03 06:48:00    8.204753   False
2011-01-03 06:49:00    8.121145   False
2011-01-03 06:49:59    8.129115   True
2011-01-03 06:51:00    8.160426   False
2011-01-03 06:52:00    8.301057   False
2011-01-03 06:53:00    8.342608   False
2011-01-03 06:53:59    8.390675   False
```

this should be the output

Comment: So basically you want to see if there are at least 10 values within each 10 minute time bin, where the time bins are (00-10, 10-20, 20-30...)?

Comment: Is your data 2 columns?  what is the second column for?

Comment: @ALollz no, not bins concepts, I want to take the total 10 minutes of data, like an example i have given, if you see only 3 values are coming in 10 minutes, then it jumps to 6:39:00, and then it will give the next 10 minutes of data

Comment: @DemetriP Actually its only one column, I set that date time as an Index, so its coming that way, i just copied my data here.

Comment: Can you please format it more appropriately?

Comment: @DemetriP okey let me check what I can do

Comment: @DemetriP i hope this will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I got the solution and it works the way I want to I used the `floor()` and `diff()` function to achieve my answers,

I tried `df.DateTime.dt.floor('10T').diff()`
I used this code and it gives all the breakdown of 10 mints data.

reference: [Split Time Series Data Into Time Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108766/split-time-series-data-into-time-intervals-in-one-line-pythonicway-hourly)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't perfect, but it gives you `True` at the 10 minute marks.  Depends on where you start counting.

```
by_seconds = df.resample('1S')

by_seconds['flag'] = by_seconds.index.minute%10==0


DateTime                  ValA          flag
2011-01-01 00:01:00 0.5518149999999999  False
2011-01-01 00:01:01                     False
2011-01-01 00:01:02                     False
2011-01-01 00:01:03                     False
2011-01-01 00:01:04                     False
```

It just means your `ValA` will have `NaN` where there is no observation.

Comment: You can't resample the data?  Do you get an error?  If so, make sure the data type is a DateTime

Comment: I have an index date and time, and I can resmaple the data, but your second line is producing an error 'ValueError: cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler' and i don't want resampling at all, i know its to be done without resampling, and that's what I am looking for

Comment: Hmm, might be the version of pandas.  I don't know what problem you have with resampling, but this does exactly what you wanted.  If you are still unsatisfied, please include a desired output in your question.

Comment: i gave the desired output